# Error while restoring RDS DB Instance using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. I am trying to import a newly-restored RDS instance into terraform state

I have application module that calls a core-module from company's repository

\applications\rds\main.tf

```
module "rds" {
  source                  = "git::https://mysource-control/public/core-modules//aws/rds/rds?ref=v3.5.0" 

}
```

then I have root environment specific module that calls application module

\env\us-west-2\qa\rds\main.tf

```
module "rds" {
  source                     = "../../../../applications/rds"
}
```

On import I am getting error

```
C:\....\env\us-west-2\qa\rds>terraform import module.rds.module.rds qa-db-instane
```

> Error: Invalid address │ │   on  line 1: │    1:
> module.rds.module.rds │ │ A resource instance address is required
> here. The module path must be followed by a resource instance
> specification. ╵

For information on valid syntax, see:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/state/resource-addressing.html

Comment: What is the resource name in that nested module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the official documentation there is an example for importing RDS instances https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#import

You'll notice they mention `aws_db_instance.default` which is the Terraform resource name, followed by whatever you've named it.

In your case if the underlying resource in your nested module (for example sake, say it's called `my_db`) you'll be able to go

```
terraform import module.rds.module.rds.aws_db_instance.my_db qa-db-instance
```